# Javascript - undefined cookie value?

Tags: javascript, html

Try running the code, I know the problem is in the 1. part.
Thanks in advance,

P.S. I'm a newbie in JS.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
{
    //1. dio

    var Cookies = new Array();

    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

    //2. dio

    function saveIt(name) {
        var Cookies = new Array();
        var x = document.forms['forma'].cookievalue.value;
        if (!x)
            alert('Please fill in a value in the input box.');
        else {
            Cookies.create(name,x,7);
            alert('Cookie created');
        }
    }

    function readIt(name) {
        alert('The value of the cookie is ' + Cookies[name]);
    }

    function eraseIt(name) {
        Cookies.erase(name);
        alert('Cookie erased');
    }

    function init() {
        for (var i=1;i<3;i++) {
            var x = Cookies['ppkcookie' + i];
            if (x) alert('Cookie ppkcookie' + i + '\nthat you set on a previous visit, is still active.\nIts value is ' + x);
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name = "forma">
    <input type = "text" name = "cookievalue">
    <input type = "button" value = "Spremi" onClick = "saveIt('ppkcookie1')">
    <input type = "button" value = "Ispisi" onClick = "readIt('ppkcookie1')">   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's hard to "run the code" because you didn't supply the part that actually *calls* any of the functions, and you didn't supply the HTML for the form.

Comment: I did, it just didn't show, sorry, here, I'll update it.

Comment: Note that the `</head>` disappeared during the edit. You might want to bring it back in to avoid red herrings. You may also want to copy'n'paste'n'run it to verify if anything went right. The JS is expecting a form with name `cookieform`, but there isn't any one in the HTML...

Comment: I just realized I haven't even inserted the JS script I needed to insert. It got way too complicated for me now...
Here's the tutorial I used: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
It's all a little messed up, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Cookies.create does not seem to be a function

Comment: Cookies is an array and createCookie is a function, I tried to change it to Cookies.createCookie but it didn't do anything?

Comment: @Computeras - that's not how JS works. For one thing you have a function called FooBar and you're calling a function called Foo (different name = different object here) for another you need to assign a function to an object to use the dot notation ('Cookies.create = createCookie;' will do here) and finally your saveIt function creates a new variable in scope with the same name which wil never work. I strongly suggest you use a copy of some existing cookie manipulation code (azatoth's is as good as any, and use that to help you learn more about JS).

Comment: I don't know enough JS anyways, so I can only partially understand what you just said. So never mind. If I ever need the code for cookies again, I'm gonna use an existing code, like you said. Thanks for the effort anyway

Answer (score 0):

Following code I've had stashed away in [morebits.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:AzaToth/morebits.js); possibly you can use it straight off:

```
Cookies = {
    /*
     * Creates an cookie with the name and value pair. expiry is optional or null and defaults
     * to browser standard (in seconds), path is optional and defaults to "/"
     * throws error if the cookie already exists.
     */
    create: function( name, value, max_age, path ) {
        if( Cookies.exists( name ) ) {
            throw "cookie " + name + " already exists";
        }
        Cookies.set( name, value, max_age, path );
    },
    /*
     * Sets an cookie with the name and value pair, overwrites any previous cookie of that name.
     * expiry is optional or null and defaults to browser standard (in seconds),
     * path is optional and defaults to /
     */
    set: function( name, value, max_age, path ) {
        var cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
        if( max_age ) {
            cookie += "; max-age=" + max_age;
        }
        cookie += "; path=" + path || "/";
        document.cookie = cookie;
    },
    /*
     * Retuns the cookie with the name "name", return null if no cookie found.
     */
    read: function( name ) {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
        for( var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i ) {
            var current = cookies[i];
            current = current.trim();
            if( current.indexOf( name + "=" ) == 0 ) {
                return decodeURIComponent( current.substring( name.length + 1 ) );
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
    /*
     * Returns true if a cookie exists, false otherwise
     */
    exists: function( name ) {
        var re = new RegExp( ";\\s*" + name + "=" );
        return re.test( document.cookie );
    },
    /*
     * Deletes the cookie named "name"
     */
    remove: function( name ) {
        Cookies.set( name, '', -1 );
    }
}
```